# Pronunciation of большую

Tags: произношение

What is the right way to pronounce **большую**?

The [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9#Russian) mentions both *бо́льшую* and 
[*большу́ю*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%83), what's the difference between them?

Is this a special case that you just have to live with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Больш**а**я (with the emphasis on the "а") — is the adjective "big" for feminine nouns, like больш**а**я победа (a big victory, a big win), больш**а**я машина (a big car) etc. больш**у**ю in this case is the word больш**а**я in the genitive or accusative case.
2. Б**о**льшая (with the emphasis on the "о") — is a bit complicated. Roughly speaking, it's an equivalent of the word "bigger" in English, but with considerable catches:

   - it's used only when referring to something feminine, which/who is bigger out of several other things:

     > Which car should I buy? Take a bigger one. -> Какую машину стоит мне купить? Возьми б**о**льшую.
   - it's not used when comparing these things directly (as one can see, there is no word б**о**льшая in that case):

     > This car is bigger, than that one. -> Эта машина **больше** той
     >
     > **NOT** Эта машина б**о**льшая той

The word больш**у**ю in case 2 is the word б**о**льшая in the genitive or instrumental case, likewise in case 1.

So to summarize, **both ways are correct**, because the words are different.

To summarize all the cases of this kind (больш**а**я — б**о**льшая), here is the list (the adjectives here also have to be declined properly, this is only their initial form in the nominative case):

- больш**о**й (big) / б**о**льший (roughly "bigger") — adjectives to use with the masculine nouns
- больш**а**я (big) / б**о**льшая (roughly "bigger") — adjectives to use with the feminine nouns
- больш**о**е (big) / б**о**льшее (roughly "bigger") — adjectives to use with the so-called "middle gender" nouns

Comment: It is very unusual to use "больший" for material things. "Bозьми бОльшую машину" sounds very unnatural.

Comment: @Abakan, I'm disagreeing. Even if the example with a car is unnatural (though I don't think so), I'm sure, you'll agree that there is the established expression "большая часть". Isn't the word "part" here a "material thing" as you said?

Comment: It's not. And anyway "большая часть" (including synonyms of "часть") is almost the only case of using "больший". I doubt that you have ever heard "Возьми бОльшую" relating to any kind of physical thing in real life.

Comment: @Abakan, I consider the word "больший" as a synonymous way to say "тот, который больше остальных", "самый большой из …" etc. So I still insist, that that word is perfectly normal to use with anything at all. With physical things either. Please, consider a situation: you are observing several cars, which all are big. How can you refer to the biggest one? You can't just say "больш**а**я машина". So there are only two ways, essentially: "самая больш**а**я машина" (and its variations like "та, которая больше всех" etc.) and a shorter way — "б**о**льшая машина"

Comment: "Genitive or instrumental case" - accusative, surely???  You've got me worried that I've forgotten or misunderstood all my Russian grammar :)

Comment: Synonymous does not mean that both are used equally often. "лик" is synonymous to "лицо" but you wouldn't use "лик" in everyday life (except some special cases).

Comment: I really cannot follow that logic with "Synonymous does not mean that both are used equally often". What does it have to do with the example I gave about a man observing several big physical things. Can't he refer to the biggest one with "б**о**льшая"? I, as a native speaker, would do this. Actually, I'm surprised, that for, probably other native speakers this would sound weird. Can it be related to some local peculiarities? Like the word "разнос", which is used instead of "поднос" in the Donbass? I grew up in Kharkov and for me it is 100% normal to use "б**о**льшая" with physical things

Answer (score 9):

A compact explanation. These are two words of different *meaning* and *stress position* which doesn't vary with cases. Depending on case/gender, the two words may differ in *spelling*:

**Большо́й** (-а́я, fem.) means **big**.

**Бо́льший** (-ая, fem.) means **the bigger** (one/part - of whatever is available).

**Бо́льшую** is the accusative case (fem. gender, singular) of *бо́льшая* and **большу́ю** is the accusative case (fem. gender, singular) of больша́я (the spelling in the accusative/nominative *coincides* for feminine). The spelling here (fem. + singular) will differ for cases *other than* nominative/accusative: **большо́й/бо́льшей**.

As you can see, the *stress position* always corresponds to the initial adjective's *meaning*.